# capturing informations from web radios audio stream

Tags: audio-streaming, wireshark, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, webradio

In some web radio players, whenever a new song is put on the air, the player gives us information about the artist, the song and an image of the album. I'm thinking if there is some possibilities to capture these informations while streaming the web radio using a packet sniffer like wireshark.
If not wireshark, are there any other softwares more specialized to work with informations coming up from audio stream?

Anyone have experience in this?

Comment: Yes, that is entirely possible.  What are you trying to do?  What kind of streams?  You might find a proxy, such as Fiddler, to be much more suited for this kind of task if you are using HTTP.

Comment: @Brad thanks for your answer. The idea is to take these informations and print to a web player, I don't know what kind of stream it is. I'm new with these argument and I appreciate if you can give me more infos (links, documents or other material to study in deep these issues).

Comment: Can you better describe what you are trying to do?  Why would you use Wireshark to get data when it is available in the stream?

Comment: @Brad For example, for the web radio I'm listening (It's a national radio)  I haven't the direct link of the stream, but only the player of the website. Maybe using wireshark I can retrive informations about the link of the stream. But if I haven't this link, aren't there possibilities to catch these infos? I thought that these infos were brought in some packets during the listening

Comment: Yes, of course you can capture anything over the network, but not client-side from some web page.